# WooCommerce calculate shipping cost for one product programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I am creating a **WordPress plugin for WooCommerce** shops. For this plugin, I need at some point to be able to **calculate the shipping cost for a given product**.

The plugin operates only on the **admin side**.

**Conditions**

The shipping calculation should be made by matching the WooCommerce seller settings (shipping zones / shipping methods).

Also, I only consider the seller country to simulate a shipping inside this country (e.g. : from France to France)

At this point I already succeed to get some result, but I really need advice. Is my approach a good one? Is there a better way to achieve this? Also, if my approach is good enough, I need to complete some aspect of it.

**The code**

Here is my code with additionnal questions in the comments (comments beginning with `(?)`).

```php
  /**
   * Calculating shipping cost for a product form the shop country to the shop country
   * 
   * TODO : validating global approach
   * TODO : handle product shipping class
   * TODO : handle product taxes
   * TODO : validating $package
   * TODO : masterizing WC_Shipping_Method::get_rates_for_package
   * 
   */
  function get_product_shipping_cost( $product_id ) {

    $result = [];

    /**
     * Initializing some Woocommerce stuffs
     * This seems required, otherwise calling WC_Shipping_Method::get_rates_for_package will throw errors
     * This block of code was found here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/27157#issuecomment-665629724
     * (?) Is this approach ok ?
     */
    require_once( WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-cart-functions.php' );
    require_once( WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-notice-functions.php' );
    $woocommerce = WC();
    $woocommerce->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
    $woocommerce->session->init();
    $woocommerce->customer = new WC_Customer( );
    $woocommerce->cart = new WC_Cart();

    // The product for which to calculate the shipping cost
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    
    // The seller location is useful to automatize the shipping calculation
    $seller_location = wc_get_base_location();
    $country_code = $seller_location['country'];

    // Get the configured zone on which to base shipping calculation
    $shipping_zone = get_shipping_zone_per_country_code( $country_code );
  
    if($shipping_zone) {

      // Get all enabled shipping method values for the shipping zone
      // (?) I do not masterize the $context = 'values' parameter given here
      $shipping_methods = $shipping_zone->get_shipping_methods( true, 'values' );
      
      // Creating the package that is used by WooCommerce to make shipping calculation
      // (?) $package definition need to be validated and completed with the product tax (line_tax, line_subtotal_tax)
      $package = [
        'destination' => [
          'country'  => $country_code,
          'state'    => '',
          'postcode' => ''
        ],

        'contents' => [
          [
            'quantity' => 1,
            'data' => is_a($product, 'WC_Product_Variation') ? new WC_Product( $product->get_parent_id() ) : $product,
            'line_total' => $product->get_price(),
            'line_tax' => 0,
            'line_subtotal' => $product->get_price(),
            'line_subtotal_tax' => 0
          ], 
        ],
        'applied_coupons' => [],
        'contents_cost' => $product->get_price()
      ];

      // Feeding the result 
      $result['zone_id']   = $shipping_zone->get_id();
      $result['zone_name'] = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name();
      $result['shipping_methods'] = [];

      // Loop through Shipping methods
      foreach ( $shipping_methods as $instance_id => $shipping_method ) {

        $cost = "";
        
        // Calculating cost for the shipping methods
        // (?) In what use case is it possible to get several rates per shipping method ?
        $rates = $shipping_method->get_rates_for_package($package);
        if( count($rates) ) { 
          $rate = array_shift($rates); // (?) Getting the first rate because I don't see why I should get several
          $cost = $rate->get_cost();

          // Get Shipping method title (label)
          $title = $shipping_method->get_title();
          $title = empty($title) ? $shipping_method->get_method_title() : $title;

          $result['shipping_methods'][] = [
            'shipping_method_id' => $instance_id, 
            'shipping_method_title' => $title, 
            'shipping_cost'         => $cost,
          ];
        }
        
      }
    }

    return $result;
  }

  /**
   * Given a specific country code this function search for WooCommerce Shipping Zone
   * and return the first zone matching with the country code
   */
  function get_shipping_zone_per_country_code( $country_code )
  {
    $all_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
    foreach($all_zones as $zone_id => $zone) {
      $zone_locations = $zone['zone_locations'];
      foreach($zone_locations as $location){
        if( $location->code == $country_code){
          return new WC_Shipping_Zone($zone['id']);
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

```php
// Testing the code
var_dump( get_product_shipping_cost( 1602 ) );
```

```php
// The displayed result
array(3) {
  ["zone_id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["zone_name"]=>
  string(6) "FRANCE"
  ["shipping_methods"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["shipping_method_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["shipping_method_title"]=>
      string(24) "Colissimo sans signature"
      ["shipping_cost"]=>
      string(4) "4.95"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["shipping_method_id"]=>
      int(19)
      ["shipping_method_title"]=>
      string(13) "Mondial Relay"
      ["shipping_cost"]=>
      string(4) "3.67"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["shipping_method_id"]=>
      int(38)
      ["shipping_method_title"]=>
      string(7) "Forfait"
      ["shipping_cost"]=>
      string(5) "15.00"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are asking too many questions at once. Note that in your last function `get_shipping_zone_per_country_code( $country_code )`, you should replace `if( $location->code == $country_code ){` with `if( 'country' === $location->type && $location->code == $country_code ){` as the **location type** can be a **"continent"**, a **"state"**, a **"country"** or a **"postcode"**...